# For inside a makefile

Tags: makefile

Hello all I have a pretty big makefile on linux and I am reducing it. For such task I am trying to reduce the variable declaration section (small example bellow)

```
DIRHEA := include/

DIRHEA_MANAGERS := $(DIRHEA)managers/
DIRHEA_ENTITIES := $(DIRHEA)entities/

CXXFLAGS := -I$(DIRHEA_MANAGERS) -I$(DIRHEA_ENTITIES)
```

Trying to do something that works in the following way,

```
for dir in $(DIRHEA)/*; do \ 
    if [[ -d $dir ]]; then \
        CXXFLAGS += -I$dir \
    fi; \
done
```

Which has not worked. Can anyone please suggest me a way to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First get a list of the directories:

```
SUBDIRS := $(shell ls -p $(DIRHEA) | grep /)
```

Then

```
CXXFLAGS := $(addprefix -I(DIRHEA), $(SUBDIRS))
```

Answer (score 1):

`for` loops like that are **shell** syntax, not Makefile. You will need to use the syntax of your shell (`foo="${foo} bar"` in POSIX compatible shells) to concatenate strings.